# Can I include a non-Symfony class?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, symfony1

I'm actually learning Symfony and I don't understand the fact of including classes. Can I include a standalone class - this means, not designed for a framework - and then use it - let's say, Amazon S3 class -?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put your class in wherever lib (sub)directory it suits you the best. It will be autoloaded by the framework.

If you don't want it to be automatically autoloaded than put it somewhere in the lib/vendor directory.

If your class is reusable than it's the best to put it in a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply kuba. I mean, I can invoke the class like always ($foo = new bar()) and then use its methods also ($foo->example())?

Comment: Symfony will autoload just like kuba said. And you can use it just like you would use a Symfony class or any other PHP class.

Comment: Don't you need the filename to end .class.php?

Comment: @Maerlyn not really. All the propel files don't follow that convention.